# Weird body padding on mobile layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you go to https://www.biznessapps.com on mobile layout, inspect element in Google Chrome and disable `overflow-x: hidden` from `body` and resize again, then you will find the white vertical stripe (padding) in the right side.

I had to add `overflow-x:hidden` to body to hide this, but not sure what causes this. Is there any other way than using `overflow-x:hidden` ?

[image]

Comment: I don't see it, have you tried refreshing the page after going into emulation mode? (chrome debugging is good, but has a few quirks, e.g. the scroll bar needs a page refresh to change to mobile mode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So what you are doing with the `overflow-x` solution is a viable solution, but if you'd like to learn how to debug ghost elements, read below:

Basically, I debugged your site and saw that some of your sections (mainly ones in columns of 2 or 3, that float) extend past the wrapper's width. You can see this as well by inputting this into your CSS

```
*{
    background: #000 !important;
    color: #0f0 !important;
    outline: solid #f00 1px !important;
}
```

Scroll down and look for sections that extend past the main div, such as this: [image: extended section]

Most of these are the results of a little extra margin or padding on the floated section.

---

- Like I said, the `width:100%;` and `overflow-x:hidden;` is still a very common solution, this is just how to debug it if you'd like to fix the structure.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate your kind debugging and recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

It's a scroll bar. Since the default behaviour for overflow is to add the scroll bar,

`overflow-x: visible;`

might be the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbar some times visible and shows like extra padding or margin in body hiding overflow-x will work.

```
html, body {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```